# browserSync при обновлении CSS прыгает страница

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

При обновлении страницы через `gulp + browserSync` прыгает страница в самый верх, хотя редактирую `footer`.

Такое происходит именно с `CSS`, и через раз, притом когда это случается, кнопки на сайте прыгают (расширяются как бы), и происходит такая вспышка белая, как будто по новой страницу обновили.

Гуглил, у многих такая проблема, но решение так никто и не написал... Очень неудобно, потому что приходится в самый низ скроллить...

```js
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      indentType: 'tab',
      indentWidth: 1
    }).on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      browserSync.notify(err.message, 3000);
      this.emit('end');
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions'], {
      cascade: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'css-libs', 'scripts'], function () {
  gulp.watch('app/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: "в самый низ скролить.." извините ошибся

Comment: Я поправил. На будущее: вы можете редактировать свои вопросы и ответы

Comment: Спасибо, искал кнопку, не нашел, потом только увидел в самом низу под постом..

Comment: Понял почему прыгает страница, если сделать слежение только за style.scss то всё норм а если все файлы выбирать то страница прыгает.. надо как то это решить

Comment: Если у кого то будет подобная проблема - скачок вверх происходил из за компиляции media.scss, не знаю почему, но удалил файл с медиа запросами и всё стало норм, притом там небыло никаких правил кроме обычного шаблона под разные разрешения, но они были все пустые.. в общем в этом дело было) ну ничего, буду напрямую в media.css писать, scss не очень то и нужен в медиа запросах

Answer (score 0):

я решил проблему так но у меня (gulp alfa 4)

```js
return gulp.src("source/sass/main.sass", { since: gulp.lastRun('sass') })
    .pipe(cached('sass'))
    .pipe(remember('sass'))
    .pipe(debug({ title: "sass" }))
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' })).on('error', notify.onError())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css')).resume()
        // .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
    });

gulp.task('serve', function () {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "http://188.243.241.229/REN.v.0.0/"

    });

    browserSync.watch("source/sass/main.sass").on('change', browserSync.stream);

    browserSync.watch("css/*.*").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    browserSync.watch("*.*").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    browserSync.watch("js/*.*").on('change', browserSync.reload);

});
```